# Installing Wordpress in another Install?

Tags: permalinks, installation

I'm trying to install one wordpress site in a different directory on the same server as another, and access it as a sub-directory of the site. Maybe this describes better-

File structure:

```
public_html/
  index.php
  wp/ # main install
  2012/ # secondary install
```

The desired url structure:

mydomain.com/ (this points to the main install in the **wp** folder)

mydomain.com/2012/ (this points to the secondary install in the **2012** folder)

I can tell that the database is connected correctly on both installs. And the primary install is working fine, but I think the permalink settings of the primary install are interfering with the requests for the secondary install. Does anyone have any suggestions?

The .htaccess file in the root folder:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Why not convert your primary install into a [Multisite Setup](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network)? It's very simple and effective.

Comment: Edit the question to have the contents of your .htaccess files, so that people can see if there is any issue with them possibly interfering.

Comment: @NWTech - this seems like a good option, but this statement from the codex is a little discouraging: "You cannot choose Sub-directory Install (for a path-based network) if your existing WordPress installation has been set up for more than a month, due to issues with existing permalinks." http://codex.wordpress.org/Before_You_Create_A_Network

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a cacheing plug-in (W3TotalCache) installed on the secondary site which prevented it from updating to the new url settings and displaying correctly. I had to completely delete the plug-in and all related files to enable the site again.